# Loop in firebase firestore + angular documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application with Angular and using firebase firestore to store the data.
I need to loop through all documents in a collection, and return all documents that have a specific ID.

[image: database firestore]

This is the firestore database, so I need to go through all the documents that are within the "projects" collection, and I need it to return all the documents that have the ID I'm looking for (note that I'm not looking for the document ID , but rather, an id that is saved within the document) in this case, it is the ID of the user who created the project.

When I go to save a new project, I take the UID of the logged in user and save it within the document. I need to print all projects from user X, So, I need to go through all the documents in the collection and only search for those that have the ID in question.

```
  async userProjectsList(id: any) {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, "projects");
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      return docSnap.data()
    } else {
      return console.log("Document not found!")
    }
  }
```

With the code above I can search for all projects that are within the "projects" collection, but I need to search only for those that have a specific ID (which in this case are all projects from the same user), but I'm not succeeding. . Can someone help me?

```
const docRef = doc(this.firestore, "projects", id);
```

With this snippet of code I could search for the document ID, but that's not what I need... I need to search for an ID that is within each document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [querying data in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and the documentation on [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), you can use an equality condition to get the documents with the matching `id` field value. The

Based on that

````
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "projects"), where("id", "==", "CWQefqp1rsc0R9JIghPLCwXJL9M2"));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});```
````

Comment: Perfect! worked correctly. Thanks for the answer, I can't rate it because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: No worries André, just good to hear that it works. After a certain amount of time the system will allow you to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), since you are the one that posted the question.